# Change draggable containment on scale

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, draggable

I want to create a template editor, with a parent and inside the child div (this can be a4, a5 and more other sizes). Real a4 in px =  2480 X 3508px so can't display entire div(child) on a standard screen. This is why i use scale (zoom in/out).

If page child is bigger than parent, I have to drag it to be visible - the problem is how can I change containment on draggable.

html:

```
<div class="bigDiv">
    <div class="smallDiv" id="draggable"></div>
</div>
```

js:

```
var offTop = $(".bigDiv").offset().top;
var offLeft = $(".bigDiv").offset().left;
var $draggable = $("#draggable");
var $container = $(".bigDiv");
var top = offTop + $container.height() - $draggable.height();
var bottom = top + $draggable.height()  - $container.height();
var left = offLeft + $container.width() - $draggable.width();
var right = left + $draggable.width() - $container.width();
$("#draggable").draggable({ 
    containment: [left,top,right,bottom]
    //containment:'parent'
});
```

As you can see, current containment works with bigger child, but if child is smaller, can't drag it any more and need commented containment. Hope you get it :)

Example here: This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xt25du2j/66/).

Any help please? Thanks!

Comment: your child is actually draggable when you change your containment to `parent`. I'm not really sure about your problem. It's pretty confusing

Comment: so curent drag is ok if page is at 100% size, but on zoom out eg 25% when child is smaller than parent, cant drag it with this containment, also need to fit it with parent margins, I don't want to get outside

Comment: -Hi how did you resolved this issue